# Когда запускаю файл PyGame, он сразу же закрывается

Tags: pygame

Статья - https://pythonru.com/primery/streljalka-s-pygame-5-uluchshennye-stolknovenija
Пожалуйста, напишите ответ, а не исправленный код

````
import random
from os import path

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)


class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = meteor_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = int(self.rect.width * .85 / 2)
        # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        # убить, если он заходит за верхнюю часть экрана
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()


# Загрузка всей игровой графики
background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "starfield.png")).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "playerShip1_orange.png")).convert()
meteor_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "meteorBrown_med1.png")).convert()
bullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "laserRed16.png")).convert()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)

# Цикл игры
running = True
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверка для закрытия окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    # Обновление
    all_sprites.update()

    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)

    # Проверка, не ударил ли моб игрока
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    if hits:
        running = False

    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\какой-то путь\какой-то файл.py", line 19, in 
pygame.init()
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined

Нужно написать import random, pygame